Accepted new moderator agreement still showing notification on meta site
I accepted the new moderator agreement about a week ago. The site I help moderate (Arts & Crafts) is very small, so I only just yesterday visited its meta site again. There I was met with the notification once more:


The new Moderator Agreement is ready for you to accept. You have until August 8, 2024, to review it and make your decision.


Clicking the "new Moderator Agreement" link (seen in the image above), I get send to the same page I visited earlier, the one with the new agreement, but it clearly indicates—at the top and at the bottom—that I have indeed already accepted it.
On the Moderator Dashboard, there is no star indicating that I have not accepted it, either (thanks, αλεχολυτ!).
The notification is gone now (August 9th). I believe (or, rather, presume) that's been the case since August 8th.

I see no reason to have to accept it separately for the main and meta sites I moderate (even though this has been brought up before), so I'm guessing this is a bug.

Possibly related to:

Accepting the Moderator Agreement doesn't seem to work right away (I didn't dismiss the notification yet, and it keeps showing up, after refresh and page reload)
Moderator Agreement notice disappeared without dismissing it (the difference is that I did accept it, a while ago)


Possible regression (with the notification though, not the acceptance): Unify Main and Meta Mod agreements so that newly appointed moderators only have to accept the agreement once
